# How to add MathType and ChemType plugin in CKeditor5-ReactJS or .Net?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I need to implement CKEditor5 whith Mathtype and Chemtype in existing ReactApp. Please help if anyone have implemented or any demo.

Comment: have you tried simply googling `ckeditor 5 reactjs`? The first result I get is the [CKEditor's React](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html) page with several examples. Have you tried something? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot,                                                                                                                                        
Yes I have tried a lot and almost for 3 days but I couldn't success to implement MathType and ChemType in my editor using react.